# Error while loading ssrs report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I got the following error while loading data using ssrs report:

> Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error
>   occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code
>   returned from the server was: 12031

My Data is not large.

Comment: Do you use an updatepanel?

Answer (score 2):

This error may be due to the HTTP Runtime limitation of the maxRequestLength.  The default value is 4096.

Try adding (or editing) the following entry in your Web.Config:
`"<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="8192"  />"`
 (effectively allowing 8mb of data transmission, instead of the default 4mb).

You'll want to enter this in the System.Web configuration section.